# Windows 10 strange unnamed floating text on the screen

Tags: windows-10

As per the attached screen shot.

Not too sure what causes that text to float on the screen no matter what page or windows or application are running, it is floating on top.  Is there a way to reset it other than a restart?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Either restart explorer.exe, log out and log back in, or perform a retract.  It's just a graphical glitch

Comment: how to perform a retract ?

And do you call this glitch, is there a well known name for it ?

Comment: I clearly meant a *restart*;  The well known name for it, is a graphical glitch, which is what I called it.

Comment: Microsoft's artificial intelligence get out of control and training itself on your private browsing behavior :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify which program has left a portion of its UI floating on my screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/1544706/how-to-identify-which-program-has-left-a-portion-of-its-ui-floating-on-my-screen)